# Updating A Filemaker Database From An Imported List

Tags: barcode-scanner, filemaker, inventory

I have a large Filemaker 12 database with current inventory items, about 100 fields per record and about 10,000 records. Physical inventory is currently done by hand. What I would like to do it with a bar code scanner which spits out an ASCII list of serial numbers separated by carriage returns.

What I need to figure out is: how to write a script taht will import the list of serial numbers we have scanned into another table, and then one by one match the serial number in the import table to a serial number in inventory, and then enter a check mark or text (present for example) into a new field in the inventory table which will let me know that it is present.

Comment: In general, marking records is bad practice. You are describing what should happen after **one** inventory taking. How would this work when the inventory is taken again? (The answer is: "not too well.") Consider creating a record for each inventory taking (if your scanner outputs a list, then you need only two fields: a date and the list), then using a **relationship** to indicate which products are present in each list.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider expanding your question to include more details about how you are trying to implement your solution, the tables you already have, and the relationship between them.

One way to use a barcode scanner to update text on your inventory table would be as follows:

1. Create a new table, we'll call this one `barcode scans`
2. On the table, create a text field, we'll call this `serial numbers`
3. When you create the table 'barcode scans' a table occurrence (also called 'barcode scans') should be created for you in the Relationships diagram in Manage Database.
4. Create an = relationship between `barcode scans::serial numbers` and `inventory::serial number`
5. Create a layout for the table occurrence of `barcode scans`
6. On the layout place the text field `barcode scans::serial numbers`
7. With the barcode scanner it sounds like you will get a return-delimited list of serial numbers in this field if you start scanning into it.
8. Create a script, we'll call it `Mark Items Present`
9. The first step of `Mark Items Present` is [`Go To Related Records`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/11/fmp/html/scripts_ref1.36.20.html). Set the options to show only related records and only for the current record. Have it go to your inventory layout. Due to the [multi key relationship](http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/71024-how-does-multikey-relationships-work/) you set up in step 4, this will find all of the indices in inventory that were scanned in `barcode scans`.
10. The second step of the `Mark Items Present` script is [`Replace Field Contents`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.54.html). Set it to the field you want to fill with "present" and set the calculation to "present". This will mark all of the records in the found set (which should be only the scanned records because of the step above) with "present".

Comment: Step 9 is redundant: you can replace the related field's contents right from where you are at that point. In any case, I would forgo the marking altogether (see my comment above) and use (for example) conditional formatting to indicate the presence of a product in the scanned list.

Comment: You're right, while step 9 isn't necessary, I included it because I believe it is a helpful step for newer users to understand what is actually happening. I also agree that marking records isn't an ideal solution if a user will be taking inventory repeatedly--but it is what is asked for in the original question.